# Internet Explorer 11/Edge submits form with one input when submit button is disabled on enter, but not with two or more inputs

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I don't know if this is a bug or if this behavior is intended, and if it is intended I can't figure out why.  If I have a form with a single input and disabled submit button, in IE11/Edge I can focus the input and hit enter and the form will be submitted.  If there are two inputs, the form is not submitted.

In Firefox and Chrome, this works as I would expect, and the form submit event is not triggered on either example while the button is disabled.

**One input ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fs13cLa6/))**

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="stuff" />
  <button type="submit" disabled>submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {alert('form submitted');});
$('button').on('click', function() {alert('button clicked');});
$('input').on('input', function() {
    if ($('#stuff').val().trim())
    $('button').prop('disabled', false);
  else
    $('button').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

**Two inputs ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fs13cLa6/4/))**

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="stuff1" />
  <input type="text" id="stuff2" />
  <button type="submit" disabled>submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {alert('form submitted');});
$('button').on('click', function() {alert('button clicked');});
$('input').on('input', function() {
    if ($('#stuff1').val().trim() && $('#stuff2').val().trim())
    $('button').prop('disabled', false);
  else
    $('button').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Why does the form with two inputs work correctly in IE11/Edge but not the form with one input?

Comment: I see, that is strange.  Have you tried having a submit button for each input? Are you wanting the <enter> key to submit both inputs?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE

Comment: @JeffArries - Ideally I would like the behavior to match FF and Chrome, where the form does not get submitted when the enter button is pressed if the submit button is disabled.

Comment: Understand better now.  I don't have any ideas, I use safari, so it's kind of hard to test. Sorry! As @Strelok said, I suggest you contact Microsoft.

Comment: The work around in the mean time could be adding an empty "hidden" input to the form which will hopefully trick Edge into not submitting it.

Comment: That does seem to work as a temporary fix (having another input with display set to none), in the meantime I have [filed a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/2428275/internet-explorer-11-edge-submits-form-when-button-disabled-with-one-field-on-enter-but-not-two-or-more), thanks for the advice!